# Invalid attempt to call Read when the reader is closed

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have written the following code for reading data from my SQL Server database, but it throws an exception:

> Invalid attempt to call `ReadAsync()` when the reader is closed.

I've debugged my code. Remarks inline the code.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    List<Categorie> hfds = new List<Categorie>();

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, naam, beschrijving from categorie", conn))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync(); // connection string is ok

                using (DbDataReader reader = await comm.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync()) // on this line give compiler a 
                                                     // exception when he comes to the 
                                                     // line for the second time.
                    {
                        int id = (int)reader["ID"];

                        Categorie c = new Categorie()
                        {
                            Naam = reader["naam"].ToString(),
                            ID = id,
                            Beschrijving = reader["beschrijving"].ToString()
                        };

                        c.TopVijf = await TopicController.GeefTopVijfTopicsVanCategorie(id, conn);
                        hfds.Add(c); 
                        // after one time running the loop is everyting alright.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Er is een exception geworpen: {ex.Message}!", "Exception");
        return View(new HomeViewModel());
    }

    return View(new HomeViewModel() { Categorieen = hfds });
}

public static async Task<List<Topic>> GeefTopVijfTopicsVanCategorie(int catId, SqlConnection conn)
{
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("declare @catid int = @id; declare @aantal int = (select top 1 MinTwee + MinEen + nul + PlusEen + PlusTwee from topic where categorieID = @catid and verwijderd = 0); if (@aantal = 0) set @aantal = 1; select top 5 id, mintwee, mineen, nul, pluseen, plustwee, naam from topic where CategorieID = @catid and verwijderd = 0 order by round(cast((mintwee * (-2) + mineen * (-1) + nul * 0 + pluseen * 1 + PlusTwee * 2) as float) / @aantal, 1) desc, creatie desc", conn))
    {
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", catId) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int });

        await conn.OpenAsync();

        List<Topic> topics = new List<Topic>();

        using (DbDataReader reader = await comm.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                topics.Add(new Topic()
                {
                    ID = (int)reader["id"],
                    Naam = reader["naam"].ToString(),
                    MinTwee = (int)reader["mintwee"],
                    MinEen = (int)reader["mineen"],
                    Nul = (int)reader["nul"],
                    PlusEen = (int)reader["PlusEen"],
                    PlusTwee = (int)reader["PlusTwee"]
                });
            }

            reader.Close();
        }

        return topics;
        // also here must be everything good.
    }
}
```

See also that there are two `DbDataReaders` in one. I thing that this is my problem, but I don't know how I can solve it. Can you help me?

Comment: You use many `await SomeAsyncOperationReturningATask()`: why?

If you call an async method and immediately await for it's completition, why not all the corresponding sync method (e.g. `conn.Open()` vs `await conn.OpenAsync()`)?

Comment: @GianPaolo: I have heard that you must use for every possible task make a new thread. I'm not sure that it is correct. Can you say why you don't use the `await`?

Comment: use async method you you want to start something on a different thread, keep calling thread working and await for task completion later in the method. 

But in your way you simply start a work in a different thread, and then your code will be something as "ok, it's just started, let me wait for it". So main thread will have to wait the same time required for the sync method, and you have just added some overhead for thread switching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it! I have place this code out site the first `SqlCommand`.

```
c.TopVijf = await TopicController.GeefTopVijfTopicsVanCategorie(id, conn);
```